# Sorting tuples in alphabetical order without built-in sort

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

If I have a list of tuples that such as `names = [('first1,last1'), ('first2,last2'),...]`

I know I can sort them alphabetically with the built-in `sort` by simply doing

`sorted_names = sorted(names, key=lambda tup: (tup[1],tup[0]))`

However, I want to know how exactly python is using the key. For instance, if I wanted to make my own sort function with a key parameter how would it be implemented? My guess would be something like

```
def my_sort(list, key):
    interpret the key in some way
    sort the list based on the key
    return list
```

I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213033/sort-list-of-list-with-custom-compare-function-in-python), it shows how to write custom comparator.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting. The implementation of sorting CPython uses is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). The key is used to convert each item in the thing you're sorting into a single value that reflects how you want it to be sorted (in this case, that value is *also* a tuple). If you're asking how Python sorts tuples: element-wise.

Comment: See also: [How is sorted(key=lambda x:) implemented behind the scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078689/how-is-sortedkey-lambda-x-implemented-behind-the-scene)

Comment: @jonsharpe okay yeah I overlooked the part on converting it to a single value, that makes things much easier